# How to re-use choice element across multiple flows?

Tags: spring, mule

I have a mule-config file where i have defined a "http inbound" to accept request on the corresponding URL.

Now what i have to to is to accept only a valid http inbound address and reject others.

So i have applied a "choice" filter to filter out valid URL's. (like the following) :

```
<flow name="abc">
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:1212/jcore/abc" 
transformer-refs="HttpParams" responseTransformer-refs="JavaObjectToJson" 
contentType="application/json" encoding="UTF-8">

    </http:inbound-endpoint>

    <component class="main.java.com.jcore.abc"/>

    <choice>
        <when evaluator="header" 
expression="INBOUND:http.request.path=/jcore/abc/a">

            <vm:outbound-endpoint path="ToSomething"/>

        </when>

         <when evaluator="header" 
expression="INBOUND:http.request.path=/jcore/abc/b">

            <vm:outbound-endpoint path="ToSomething"/>

        </when>

        <otherwise>
            <message-properties-transformer>
                <add-message-property key="http.status" value="404"/>
            </message-properties-transformer>
            <expression-transformer>
                <return-argument evaluator="string" 
expression="{&quot;Exception&quot;: &quot;Could not Render the Request. 
URL may be wrong&quot;}"/>
            </expression-transformer>
        </otherwise>

    </choice>

</flow>
```

**It is Working ..!!**

But i have around 30 "Flows" like this one. And i want to apply "choice" filter like this on every flow.

**Note** : *the matching URL will get changed in each case. Like in this case it is "/abc/a". In others , it is different*

So, i wanted to know, if there is a way to avoid writing much of this redundant code and make a Spring bean with parameters OR sumthing else, that i can apply on each flow..??

Comment: What about the VM outbound destinations (ToSomething): will they be all the same or will they change?

Comment: It is like : "If one URL (like '/jcore/abc/a'), then outbound to VM1 , and if another URL , outbound to VM2, for all Flows.". I mean there are only TWO VM's, which can server as Outbound Endpoint. But on the basis of URL (in Choice filter), the flow will be directed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd separate the path validation logic from the actual request handling logic, which I will make generic, configurable, and shared across flows via a flow-ref construct.

Something like this:

```
<flow name="abc">
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:1212/jcore/abc"
        contentType="application/json" encoding="UTF-8" />

    <message-properties-transformer scope="invocation">
        <add-message-property key="supported.request.paths"
                              value="/jcore/abc/a,/jcore/abc/b"/>
    </message-properties-transformer>    
    <flow-ref name="request-handler" />
</flow>

<flow name="request-handler">
    <script:component>
        <script:script engine="groovy">
            def requestPath = message.getInboundProperty('http.request.path')
            def supportedPaths = message.getInvocationProperty('supported.request.paths')
            def requestPathOk = supportedPaths.split(',').toList().contains(requestPath)
            message.setInvocationProperty('request.path.ok', requestPathOk)
            return message
        </script:script>
    </script:component>
    <choice>
        <when evaluator="header" expression="INVOCATION:request.path.ok=true">
            <vm:outbound-endpoint path="ToSomething" exchange-pattern="request-response" />
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <message-properties-transformer>
                <add-message-property key="http.status" value="404" />
            </message-properties-transformer>
            <expression-transformer>
                <return-argument evaluator="string"
                    expression="{&quot;Exception&quot;: &quot;Could not Render the Request. URL may be wrong&quot;}" />
            </expression-transformer>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
</flow>
```

Comment: I dont know why, but it is not working in my case. Actually whats happening is that, the private Flow ("request-handler") that u mentioned is not getting the actual payload from the Base Flow ("abc" in this case). For Eg : The component class (component class="main.java.com.jcore.abc") generates a Payload , but it is not getting routed to "request-handler"..!! :(

Comment: Apologies, I forgot "return message" at the end of the component :(

Comment: See what I wanted was that "payload/message should be routed to private flow and then VM endpoint defined in the private flow transforms the payload/message and return it to main Flow."..Now by adding "return message", the private flow is returning the same payload/message that it is getting, not the transformed one..!! :-O

Comment: Nah, it's not the "return message" that does what you say, it's the fact that the VM endpoint is in-only by default. I've added: exchange-pattern="request-response" - The remote VM endpoint should have the same exchange pattern. Try it.

Comment: It was already "request-response"..!! (i forgot to mention that)....
Is there any other way..??

Comment: Are both VM endpoints request-response? If you don't get an answer it's because something downstream, below "ToSomething" doesn't return a response. I've even tried with a fake Something service (here: http://pastebin.com/f6Fr3XzD) and it works, the response come back from the above routing infrastructure. I'm positive my solution works and your problem is elsewhere downstream. Please accept this solution and open another question if you want to delve in the "no response returned" issue specifically.

Comment: I can assume that this answer is correct. But whenever i have used the same VM enpoints in the choice filter (i.e. without referring the private flow ), the response come back from the VM endpoints in the main flow.. :-O ..thats why i thought there may be something fishy with this private flow.. :-O

Comment: Illustrate the issue you're alluding to with a configuration sample please, otherwise it is impossible to help you.